# Is it possible to refactor this nHibernate Linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

Currently I have the following code:

```
switch (publicationType)
{
    case PublicationType.Book:
        return Session.Query<Publication>()
            .Where(p => p.PublicationType == PublicationType.Book)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.DateApproved)                        
            .Take(10)
            .Select(p => new PublicationViewModel
            {
                ...
            });
    case PublicationType.Magazine:
        return Session.Query<Publication>()
            .Where(p => p.PublicationType == PublicationType.Magazine)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.DateApproved)                        
            .Take(10)
            .Select(p => new PublicationViewModel
            {
                ...
            });
    case PublicationType.Newspaper
    .... 
}
```

As you can see the query is the same each time except for the publicationType condition. I tried to refactor this by creating a method that takes a Func e.g.

```
private IEnumerable<PublicationViewModel> GetPublicationItems(Func<PublicationType, bool>> pubQuery)
{
    return Session.Query<Publication>()
        .Where(pubQuery)                
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.DateApproved)                        
        .Take(10)
        .Select(p => new PublicationViewModel
        {
            ...
        });                
}

private bool IsBook(PublicationType publicationType)
{
    return publicationType == PublicationType.Book;
}
```

and then calling this method like

```
GetPublicationItems(IsBook);
```

But when I do this I get the error:
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlParameter' to type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBooleanExpression'.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you don't really need a function - you just need a `PublicationType`:

```
private IEnumerable<PublicationViewModel>
    GetPublicationItems(PublicationType type)
{
    return Session.Query<Publication>()
        .Where(p => p.PublicationType == type)
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.DateApproved)                        
        .Take(10)
        .Select(p => new PublicationViewModel
        {
            ...
        });                
}
```

If you *really* need it more general than that, you probably just need to change your code to use an expression tree instead of a delegate (and change the input type):

```
private IEnumerable<PublicationViewModel> GetPublicationItems(
    Expression<Func<Publication, bool>> pubQuery)
{
    return Session.Query<Publication>()
        .Where(pubQuery)                
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.DateApproved)                        
        .Take(10)
        .Select(p => new PublicationViewModel
        {
            ...
        });                
}
```

You won't be able to call it with `GetPublicationItems(IsBook)` at that point though. You could do:

```
GetPublicationItems(p => p.PublicationType == PublicationType.Book)
```

Or:

```
private static readonly Expression<Func<Publication, bool>> IsBook =
    p => p.PublicationType == PublicationType.Book;


...

GetPublicationItems(IsBook)
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. I made my example a little too simple and as you pointed out I could just pass the publicationType straight into the query. But the generalization you posted after that was exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't just use publicationType in the query?

```
return Session.Query<Publication>()
       .Where(p => p.PublicationType == publicationType)
       .OrderByDescending(p => p.DateApproved)                        
       .Take(10)
       .Select(p => new PublicationViewModel
       {
           ...
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was confusing Delegates with Expression trees.

Func is a delegate, that cannot be turned into SQL.
You could just have written it like so:

```
Session.Query<Publication>()
.Where(p => p.PublicationType == yourPubilcationType)
...
```

Or, if you want to pass a filter that method, like you hinted in your sample:

```
IEnumerable<PublicationViewModel> GetPublicationItems(Expression<Func<PublicationType, bool>> pubQuery)
{
    return Session.Query<Publication>()
        .Where(pubQuery)                
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.DateApproved)                        
        .Take(10)
        .Select(p => new PublicationViewModel
        {
            ...
        });                
}
```